# SQL INSERT (select) using CASE based on another columns value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an alarm trigger, and if that alarm trigger = 1, I want the value of another column to be NULL.  For examples purposes, I'll create a simple table of what I'm trying to explain.

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE ( ID INT, Value1 FLOAT, V1_Alarm BIT, Value2 FLOAT, V2_Alarm BIT)
INSERT INTO @tmp
SELECT (
ID,
CASE WHEN V1_Alarm = 1 THEN NULL ELSE Value1,
V1_Alarm,
CASE WHEN V2_Alarm = 1 THEN NULL ELSE Value2
) FROM SomeTable
```

Comment: What's not working?  If you remove the parentheses,add aliases and add `END` to your `CASE` statements, what you have should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not ending your case statements properly. Also, the parentheses are unnecessary and prevent multiple values from being passed. Here's your sample code modified:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE ( ID INT, Value1 FLOAT, V1_Alarm BIT, Value2 FLOAT, V2_Alarm BIT)
INSERT INTO @tmp
SELECT  ID,
        CASE WHEN V1_Alarm = 1 THEN 
            NULL
        ELSE
            Value1
        END,
        V1_Alarm,
        CASE WHEN V2_Alarm = 1 THEN
            NULL
        ELSE
            Value2
        END
FROM    SomeTable
```

Comment: You should also mention  you removed the parentheses to allow multiple values to get passed

Comment: You have to provide V2_Alarm value as well to insert into @tmp successfully because it has not default value declared

Comment: Just adding the simple END worked :(  Thanks for the help guys.

@sllev V2_Alarm value is provided from the SELECT statement

Comment: @Tom : unfortunately I do not see V2_Alarm in select, basically fifth column value